# Answer a question using another question's answer is correct?

Tags: discussion

In short, I've answered [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/170229/gold-collector-koth/170263) `KotH` challenge using the same [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167590/78039) in this [other question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/167568/bot-outsnake-the-game).

This is my [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/170263/78039). It is not entirely copy past since I have to change some pieces of code to make it work for the other challenge but in essence, ... is the same answer...

Of course, I stated that the answer was taken from another questions' answer and gave credit to the original post.

Is this allowed here? Did I do something wrong? I feel like I just robbed it

Comment: It looks like you're OK, as you have provided attribution.

Comment: In my opinion it's similar as porting an answer in another language in the same challenge (like Jelly to 05AB1E or Python to Java or anything else). As long as you credit the one you copied from including a link like you did, I don't see any harm in it.